# Using DMA to load an image into Visual Boy Advance (VBA)

Tags: c, gameboy

I am new to C; I have an image file translated by means of online tools into a .h and .c file. The C file contains an array of 1024 16 bit hexadecimal numbers, used to denote on/off of bits. I want to read this file and draw the image onscreen using DMA...but I'm very much at a loss as to how to do this. Can anybody out there help? Does anyone even know what I'm talking about?

Comment: Just to be clear - by VBA you're talking about the "Visual Boy Advance" emulator for the Nintendo Game Boy Advance - right?  I think most people here will think of VBA as "Visual Basic for Applications".

Answer (score 4):

To draw an image onscreen, use DMA[3].  This is channel 3 of DMA for images.

This is how you set up DMA in a .h file:
http://nocash.emubase.de/gbatek.htm#gbadmatransfers

And then to draw an image using DMA:

```
#######include image.h 

DMA[3].src = (specify your image source here, where you're drawing from)

DMA[3].dst = (where you're drawing pixels to)
```

In your scenario, I think you indicate the name of the file in your source.

Keep in mind you're using POINTERS to images for src and dst.

```
DMA[3].cnt = (how many times you want to do it) | flag1 | flag2...
```

Here are some flags:
`DMA_SOURCE_FIXED` means you draw from the same pixel over and over again.  If this is what you want, then turn this bit on in cnt.
`DMA_DESTINATION_FIXED` applies that you're drawing TO the same pixel over and over again.  If this is what you want, then turn on this bit in cnt.

Otherwise, `DMA_SOURCE_INCREMENT` and `DMA_DESTINATION_INCREMENT` are on by default (if not, you can turn them on in cnt anyway).

This is what I used for VBA, so I'm sorry if this does not answer your question (I'm kind of inexperienced with C as well...).

@Michael Yes, I mean the Visual Boy Advance